# Searching with foreign charcters

Tags: search

We have a multisite installation that has Mandarin as one of its languages, and searches do not work at all for that site. Looking into it, it seems to be an issue with how Craft runs the SQL queries, specifically

```sql
MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST('+科技*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This returns zero results, but if I change it to

```sql
keywords LIKE '科技'
```

it will return the expected results. Is there a way around this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you're not using a charset/collation that supports Mandarin characters, and MySQL's full-text search (like the `MATCH` query Craft uses and you shared) is very charset/collation specific.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-cjk.html

At a minimum, you'll want to update the `searchindex` table to a collation that supports, those characters, but you'll likely want to audit other Craft tables/columns that store them as well.